# Run code at a certain time

Tags: c#, windows-services, scheduling

I'm using a C# Windows Service application where I'm having a object containing a stored procedure.

```
public class Sp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IntervalMin { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastRun { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I'm using this method to check if it's time to run:

```
public bool TimeToRun()
{
    return ((IntervalMin * 60) <= (DateTime.Now - LastRun).TotalSeconds);
}
```

The problem I have is that when the service is down during weekends and wakes up on monday `TimeToRun` will be true for all (considering `IntervalMin` isn't really high).

For example, there is one Sp with `IntervalMin = 1440` (should be runned once a day), and lets says `LastRun` is Friday 14:00, on monday when service wakes up at 03:00 it will run, but I want it to be as close as possible to 14:00.

You have any tips of how I can build this kind of schedule? Do I need to use more properties that I set? It's no problem if it's like +/- 5 minutes or even more. `TimeToRun()` is checked about every each second.

`LastRun` is currently set to `Datetime.Now`, but I would like to use `AddMinutes` to cause no extra delays.

```
LastRun = LastRun.AddMinutes(IntervalMin)
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using Task Scheduler- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7 ?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Scheduling is _hard_. Use existing libraries or simply use the Windows Task Scheduler. What exactly do you mean by _"service is down"_ and _"service wakes up"_, by the way?

Comment: There are lots of duplicate questions. Have a look at the list of related questions at the right hand side.

Comment: @CodeCaster I run the application as a Windows Sevice, not as a Schedule Task. The reason is because some Sp:s need to have an interval of 1min, and the fastest occurrence you can have on a schedule task is every 5min.

Comment: @M4N Because of the service being up only Mon-Fri, and the Sp in my example is suppose to run every weekday at 14:00 I'm not sure that I have a duplicate...Can't find a solution for that, or am I missing something?